# nodejs server for register couchdb user

Tags: android, json, node.js, couchdb

I use a nodejs server for signup user on couchdb server.

The idea is that my android app send an ajax signup request to nodejs server. The nodejs server forward that request to couchdb server and then forward the couchdb server response to the android app.

that is the code of nodejs server:

```
var dispatcher = require('httpdispatcher');
var request = require('request-json');

dispatcher.onOptions("/_users", function(req, res){
    res.writeHead(204, {'Access-Control-Allow-Origin':req.headers.origin,
        'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET, PUT, POST, HEAD, DELETE',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'authorization, x-titanium-id, content-type',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': 'true'
    });
    res.end();
});

dispatcher.onPost("/_users", function(appReq, appRes) {
    var client = request.newClient('http://localhost:5984/');
    client.setBasicAuth('admin', 'adminPassword');
    var data = JSON.parse(appReq.body);

    client.post('_users', data, function(err, res, body) {
        var appResHeader = res.headers;
        appResHeader['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = appReq.headers.origin;
        appResHeader['Access-Control-Allow-Methods'] = 'GET, PUT, POST, HEAD, DELETE';
        appResHeader['Access-Control-Allow-Headers'] = 'authorization, x-titanium-id, content-type';
        appResHeader['Access-Control-Allow-Credentials'] = 'true';
        console.log(JSON.stringify(body));
        appRes.writeHead(res.statusCode, appResHeader);
        appRes.write(JSON.stringify(body));
        appRes.end();
    });
}); 

dispatcher.onError(function(req, res) {
    res.writeHead(404, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
    res.end('Page Not Found\n');
});
```

All work well, but the response that the android app receives not contain the JSON data.

Note that
    console.log(JSON.stringify(body));

print correctly json data:

```
{"error":"conflict","reason":"Document update conflict."}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What does the answer that the client receives contain? You say it's not the JSON data, but what is it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's assume you're aware of the document update conflict (see [CouchDB's documentation](http://guide.couchdb.org/draft/api.html#revisions)) and that it is normal for your application to return this data to the Android client.

You don't need to stringify the result object yourself, let [express take care of it](http://expressjs.com/api.html#res.json). It will correctly stringify it and send the correct headers:

```
appRes.json(res.statusCode, body);
```

The same goes for CORS, you can use a middleware that does everything for you, for instance [`cors`](https://npmjs.org/package/cors).